# Ajax UpdateProgress does not stops spiniing after with a Response.Redirect

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have an UpdateProgress control to activate on a postback of a button control.  The button_click event is performing a Response.Redirect to show CSV Report. The report comes up and the UpdateProgress bar is spinning on the page with the button.  However, once the user closes the report and control is returned to the page, the UpdateProgress image is still there spinning.

How can I use the UpdateProgress bar to finish and go away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the UpdateProgress and handled the progress following way http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311028.aspx

Answer (score 6):

[This link](http://abhinavpratap.wordpress.com/2011/01/12/downloading-file-update-progress/) was helpful for me.

In short, replace the `Response.Redirect` with something like this.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
  Me, Me.GetType(), "Download", "window.location='CSV_report.aspx';", True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser knows when it sees a response with content-disposition: attachment to leave the original window open.  instead of doing a postback + response.redirect, the best option is to use a GET request, i.e. a hyperlink to a download URL.  Server.Transfer may also work instead of the Response.Redirect.